# Safari Scroll bar is not working when select list is in Div

Tags: html, css, scroll, safari

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31975798/7139696

There is solution provided in above link which I have applied in my application. But this solution is not working in safari...
can anyone please help?

The scrollbar doesn't work in safari, when pointing at div but it scrolls when pointer is at scroll bar area.

```
.wrap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.crop {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
select {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px -20px 0px 0px; /* hide unused scroll bar */
}  

<div class="wrap">
     <div class="crop"><!-- add a croping container -->
    <select multiple size="21"><!--add size attribute equal to the length of list-->
      <option>1 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>2 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>3 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>4 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>5 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>6 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>7 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>8 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>9 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>10 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>11 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>12 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>13 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>14 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>15 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>16 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>17 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>18 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>19 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>20 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
      <option>21 Vsdjflksdj fkajsdk fasjd;fkl sdaj;fk asdjf asdkljf klsdaj;f lsdajfk l;sdjkflsdjf kasd;fjl THE END</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code ?

Comment: @Shahil I have added the code. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @apaul34208 can you please help in solving this issue?